# .Net Unity Object instance issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, enterprise-library, unity-container

I really stuck trying to get unity to work for a c# project I'm working on.

Its throwing an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in my unity controller factory class.

UnityControllerFactory.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

namespace Sportrax.Presentation.Admin
{
    public class UnityControllerFactory :  DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        IUnityContainer _container;

        public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);
        }

    }
}
```

My Global.asax.cs file is:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");

            section.Containers.Default.Configure(container);

            UnityControllerFactory factory = new UnityControllerFactory(container);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

And my Web.config is:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name ="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
    </configSections>
    <unity>
        <containers>
            <container>
                <types>
                    <type type="Sportrax.Business.Interfaces.IVenueService, Sportrax.Business" mapTo="Sportrax.Business.VenueService, Sportrax.Business" />
                    <type type="Sportrax.DAL.Interfaces.IVenueRepository, Sportrax.DAL" mapTo="Sportrax.DAL.Repositories.VenueRepository, Sportrax.DAL" />
                </types>
            </container>
        </containers>
    </unity>
    ......
```

I have added project references to Microsoft.Practices.unity and
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, version 1.1.0.0.

My runtime version under those references properties says v2.0.50727

Could this be the issue? I do have two versions availble when I go to add the references?

Adding error details here (I cant attach images!):

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.Unity
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException.CreateMessage(Type typeRequested, String nameRequested, Exception innerException) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\ResolutionFailedException.cs:line 99
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException..ctor(Type typeRequested, String nameRequested, Exception innerException) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\ResolutionFailedException.cs:line 43
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\UnityContainer.cs:line 467
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\UnityContainer.cs:line 450
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\UnityContainer.cs:line 149
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerBase.Resolve(Type t) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\UnityContainerBase.cs:line 416
       at Sportrax.Presentation.Admin.UnityControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\College\MSc Web Technologies\Project .Net\Sportrax\Sportrax.Solution\Sportrax.Presentation.Admin\UnityControllerFactory.cs:line 23
       at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
  InnerException:
```

It occurs at line:

return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);

in UnityControllerFactory.cs

Comment: This thing has gotten next to impossible to follow. SO isn't a discussion forum. Answers will move up or down on the page, so saying "see end of page" doesn't work. Could you edit your original question to include your current status if you still haven't gotten an answer?

Comment: Agreed Chris, it is all over the place...sorry. Only new to SO and wasn't 100% sure on how posting worked. Think I'll close issue for now. Currently committing my stuff to repository and testing with unity on somebody else's checkout out copy. Cant afford to waste any more time trying to figure this issue out as project has to be delivered soon. I will update with an answer if I get time to look at it and get it fixed at a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting to think this is a dll instalation/config problem. It's a team project and works fine on others machines. I have deleted my projects and re-checked in a clean version into my machine.

I keep getting VisualStudio File pop-up dialog boxes when its hits the error on line 'return (IController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);' in the factory class.

The File pop up is asking to find source files: So far files asked for are: 
e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainerExtensions.cs
e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\Utility\Guard.cs
e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity.Configuration\UnityTypeResolver.cs
e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Src\Unity\ResolutionFailedException.cs"

I noticed that under 'C:\Program Files\' I have both Microsoft Unity Application Block 1.1 and Microsoft Unity Application Block 2.0 folders.

Also, I'm on Vista OS....maybe something quirky with this?

Answer (score 0):

You stumbled upon a bug in Unity, that's for sure. A reusable framework should never throw a `NullReferenceException`. You probably misconfigured it, but it is impossible to tell what the cause of this is by looking at the exception.

When I look at the `ResolutionFailedException.CreateMessage` method of Unity v2.0 using Reflector, I can't find any spot that could throw an `NullReferenceException`. Therefore you must be using an older version and I guess they fixed the error in a never version. Try using v2.0. I bet you get a better exception message in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be causing it at `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp`.  I would hazard a guess that it could be something in the constructor of one of your types?

Comment: Hi Matthew, it looks like it may be something to do with the default home controller....see my full explanation in comment at end of page.